# Change the text color of multiple textviews from activity

Tags: android

I want to change the text color of 10-15 `TextView`'s in my app, when a button is clicked. These text views are not on a single activity. Is there a way to implement this other than using the theme concept.

Comment: same color or different colors?

Comment: Same color. My main issue is how to refer to all there textviews atonce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make an `ArrayList` of `TextView` and each time you create a TextView (when you first start your app) that you want to change the text color you add it to this ArrayList.
Later on when the user click on your button you call a method which implement a loop on this ArrayList and you set your text color.

A static ArrayList may be needed to achieve this.

```
ArrayList<TextView> myAlTv = new ArrayList<TextView>();
        myAlTv.add(firstTv);
        myAlTv.add(secondTv);
        myAlTv.add(thirdTv);
        //...

public void changeColor()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < myAlTv.size(); i++)
    {
        myAlTv.get(i).setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
    }
}
```

Comment: thinks this will solve my issue.. but isn't there a much simpler way?

Comment: Not that I can see, sorry... wait a little, maybe someone smarter will help you out.

Comment: You could maybe have a changing color method for each of your Activity changing the color of the TextViews inside this particular Activity and also changing a boolean to true. So when you start another Activity when you 'reconstruct your layout' your layout will notice than the boolean change his value and so will create TextViews with the new color... it's messy, don't know if you get my point.

Comment: A good option..but finally I decided to use the theme itself. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 2):

You can use sharedPreferences to do that . When you click the button you can save the color that the textviews should have into a sharedPreferences object. And then in your other activities you can retrieve those color values via getting the sharedPreference you set before  and you can assign those color values to the textviews in the other activities easily.

Comment: Saving and retrieving the selected color is not an issue. Is there a way to refer all the text views without creating an object for a text view, change its color, then create object for the next one..

Comment: You cant access the objects without creating them but like i said you can set this property and then assign it to them at any time.